# Init programmatic VC for Storyboard VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to display a programmatically created ViewController in a storyboard ViewController. The ViewController of the Storyboard is of a different class as the 'programmatically' created ViewController.

I've got the following classes:

```
ViewController (linked to storyboard scene, and implementation happens here)
OnboardingVC (all elements are created over here)
```

I've tried the following:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.onboardVC = [self generateFirstDemoVC]; // returns in an instance ofOnboardingViewController
        self = (ViewController*)self.onboardVC;
    }

    return self;
}
```

This (obviously) crashes.

What I don't want is this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.onboardVC];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Because this doesn't take the setup in the storyboard into account, and I don't want that, because the VC needs to managed by a `NavigationController`. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a UINavigationController as the entry point to your storyboard.  You can manipulate this navigation controller when the application launches, to add, remove, or replace view controllers, etc.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions 
{
    UIViewController* initialVc = [OnboardingViewController generateFirstDemoVC]; // or whatever

    UINavigationController* nav = (id)_window.rootViewController;
    nav.viewControllers = @[ initialVc ];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this does the exact same thing.. And the view I'm trying to launch is not the initial view.